# Spring-orm 5.3.22 compatibility with Hibernate6 (Jakarta based)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-orm, hibernate-6.x

Project utilizes both hibernate-core and spring-orm.

Spring-orm v5.3 is claimed to be compatible with hibernate6 but when upgrading to Hibernate6 having compilation errors:

```
public class CustomHibernateJpaDialect extends HibernateJpaDialect {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Object beginTransaction(final EntityManager entityManager,
        final TransactionDefinition definition)
        throws PersistenceException, SQLException, TransactionException {
}
}
```

Entity manager required by method and PersistenceException thrown are from javax.persistance while hibernate6 was updated to utilize jakarta.persistance.

Thank you

Comment: `Spring-orm v5.3 is claimed to be compatible with hibernate6`, uhmm, where?

Comment: I am quite sure that Spring 5 never stated that it has any compatibility with jakarta packages. Stack with jakarta packages are Spring 6, hibernate 6, and Tomcat 10. You cannot upgrade just one.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Maybe I misunderstood something from last comment here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28007

Comment: @zawarudo But if hibernate6 requires Spring6, and spring-orm doesn't have version 6 - does it mean that it can't be upgraded until v6 will be released?

Comment: From the link that you provided, they are talking about jakarta packages, so yes, Spring 6, Hibernate 6, Tomcat 10 are jakarta, and if you want them all to work, you need them all to be on versions that support jakarta packages. You cannot upgrade only pieces and expect it to work. I personally do not understand what Tomcat 10 offers that 9 does not, when everything is ready, you can migrate.

Comment: Then you should have also looked at [issues#22128](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22128) which shows that spring 5 does not support hibernate 6. If you want to use hibernate 6 with spring, then you need to use spring 6.0.0-M5, which does only have milestone releases so far

Comment: @zawarudo tomcat 10 supports EL 4.0 and JSP 3.0, which IIRC should fix quite some issues the older versions pose

Comment: that still does not change the fact that things need to be compatible in order for them to work no matter the "fixes" that await on the other side.